# Delete query error message:"specify the table containing records u want to delete"

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I  want to delete all records from table "T" if the records are also in table D, but I am getting the error message "SPECIFY THE TABLE CONTAINING THE RECORDS YOU WANT TO DELETE".

```
DELETE T.DISCOUNT_CODE, T.PART_ID, T.SELLING_UM, T.QTY_BREAK_1, T.QTY_BREAK_2, T.QTY_BREAK_3, T.QTY_BREAK_4, T.QTY_BREAK_5, T.QTY_BREAK_6, T.QTY_BREAK_7, T.QTY_BREAK_8, T.QTY_BREAK_9, T.QTY_BREAK_10, T.UNIT_PRICE_10, T.UNIT_PRICE_3, T.UNIT_PRICE_4, T.UNIT_PRICE_5, T.UNIT_PRICE_6, T.UNIT_PRICE_7, T.UNIT_PRICE_8, T.UNIT_PRICE_9, T.UNIT_PRICE_2, T.UNIT_PRICE_1, T.DEFAULT_UNIT_PRICE
 FROM SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE AS T 
 INNER JOIN D ON T.PART_ID = D.PART_ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access does let you join on a delete.  So you can write you DELETE statement like this without naming the columns.

```
DELETE T.*
FROM SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE AS T 
INNER JOIN D ON T.PART_ID = D.PART_ID;
```

Comment: Access 2003 replies "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete".

Comment: strange because I have delete statements in Access 2003 with Inner JOINs

Comment: again, you are correct it was my bad for not testing it.  I have updated it and testing the code and it worked for me. I appreciate you correcting me.

Comment: Well, shoot!  That is the one that gave me "Could not delete from specified tables" in Access 2003.  If it works for you, guess that confirms my opinion that Access DELETE statements can be kind of odd.  :-)

Comment: it is very odd, that is why I am thrilled to be rewriting my app away from Access.

Comment: Just use the frigging QBE grid to write the basic statements if you can't write a valid Jet/ACE DELETE query by hand.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify columns in a delete statement. You also can't join on delete statements.

Basically, you delete from table . So, put all your conditional logic in a where clause.

Where recordid in (select .........)

Comment: I do not know SQL. woudl u be able to give me the complete code with the condition, so I can copy and paste?

Comment: If you don't know SQL, why aren't you using the Access QBE grid to write your queries?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new query in Access, switch to SQL View and paste this in:

```
DELETE 
FROM SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE AS T
WHERE Exists (SELECT * FROM D WHERE D.PART_ID = T.PART_ID);
```

That should work if you "run" (execute) the query.  If you want to View the affected rows without actually doing the DELETE, you can switch the query designer view to Datasheet View.  That will show you which rows will be subject to deletion, but Datasheet View only displays them ... doesn't delete them.  However, in order to switch to datasheet view, you will have to tell the query designer which fields to display.  You can do that by changing the first line to `DELETE *`.

Another approach would be to change the first line to `SELECT *` in order to view the affected records, then change back to DELETE when you're ready to delete them.

Comment: In the case of huge tables remember to have these ID fields indexed, otherwise the performance will be low